# Meta canonical and hreflang in multilanguage website

Tags: html, seo, multilingual, canonical-link, hreflang

I need some help in fixing potential errors on my multilanguage website. It has 3 languages; English, Turkish and Russian. English is default.

#### Question about homepage

When we access the page through `http://example.com/`, there are following meta data:

```
   <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />
   <link rel='alternate' href='http://example.com/' hreflang='x-default' />
   <link rel='alternate' hreflang='tr' href='http://example.com/tr' />
   <link rel='alternate' hreflang='en' href='http://example.com/en' />
   <link rel='alternate' hreflang='ru' href='http://example.com/ru' />
```

Result remains the same when we access website through `http://example.com/tr`, `http://example.com/en`, `http://example.com/ru`.

**QUESTION 1:**
Do you see any mistake in this case? Do I have anything to change to make it properly done?

#### Question about product link

The link of English page of product is: `http://example.com/item-english`
The link of Russian page of product is: `http://example.com/item-russian`

On English page I placed following meta data:

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/item-english" />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='x-default' href='http://example.com/item-english' />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='en' href='http://example.com/item-english' />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='ru' href='http://example.com/item-russian' />
```

On Russian page I placed following meta data:

```
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/item-russian" />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='x-default' href='http://example.com/item-russian' />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='en' href='http://example.com/item-english' />
    <link rel='alternate' hreflang='ru' href='http://example.com/item-russian' />
```

**QUESTION 2:**
Do you see any mistake in this case? Do I have anything to change to make it properly done?

Answer (score 0):

For Q2: Your x-default should be the same on all pages. In fact, all hreflang tags are supposed to be identical on all pages.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try this and measure result.